# Having trouble making an upload files option

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload

Trying to make a place for people to upload files to this site. I get an error when i try it. Let me know what you think. Im using codeigniter by the way

===== HTML =====

```
 <div id="upload">
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?=current_url()?>" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
        Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </form>
    <p><?=$uploadResult?></p>
</div>
```

===== PHP =====

```
 if ($this->input->post()) {
        $target_path = "../../uploads/";
        $target_path = $target_path .basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);  

        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
            $uploadResult =  "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded";
        } else {
            $uploadResult =  "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";   /* <---- Error I get */
        }
    } else {
        $uploadResult = 'didnt work at all';
    }

    echo $uploadResult;

    $this->data['uploadResult'] = $uploadResult;
```

===== ERROR =====

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: move_uploaded_file(../../uploads/notes_USH.odt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
Filename: controllers/discovery.php
Line Number: 158

Comment: You should be getting an ERROR or WARNING if it is failing, what does it/they say? Also, since you are using CodeIgniter you might want to take a look at http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

Comment: I tried using their uploading thing and couldnt get it to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so this is a little late but i just remade the whole thing with codeigniters stuff and after some tinkering with it i got it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the directory "../../uploads/" exists and you have write permission. PHP wont will create this for you.

Also, CodeIgnter have a class to handle the file upload (may be useful). You can see this in the [docs](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html).

Comment: Could it not be working because I'm not using the codeigniter class?

Comment: @DylanButh No, Code Iginiter is PHP so all native functions will work. I mentioned it because the class have utilities that you can use, eg validation of file type.